# send an element through a event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want  simply to send an element via a event so that to catch it as a parameter in a servlet, but NOT from the regular Form's button.
I would appreciate a suggestion.

```
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        $('#idSelect').change(function () {  
            $.post("SelectChange",$('#idSelect'), function () {  
            });  
        });  
   });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so, capture the value on change, then send it to the php file.

Access in the PHP with `$_POST['select_data'];`

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  $('#idSelect').change(function () {  
      var select_value = $("#idSelect").val();
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '/var/www/file-receiving-data.php',
         data: ({ select_data: select_value}),
         success: function(data) { 
            console.log("successfully sent to php file");
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: I am sorry to revert, but after some tests the servlet parameter still null. Until I dig more in ajax,  should I change something in the given code, except url?

Comment: Actually the message goes with success! The value cannot get as parameter in the servlet: I get just null with <<String select=request.getParameter("#idSelect");>>

Answer (score 0):

So, with the 1st answer (without which no chance to get it), til fix the other simpler permanently, the working solution is:

In servlet:

```
String val = request.getParameter("val");
```

In jsp, append the value to the url, as follows:

```
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        $('#idSelect').change(function () {  
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  
            xhttp.open("POST", "SelectChange?val="+$('#idSelect').val(), true);  
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("String", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
            alert("send de POST: "+$('#idSelect').val());  
            xhttp.send();  
        });
    });
</script>
```